# How to make the Logistic Regression model work for other files to do prediction in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I have created a Logistic Regression model for train.csv which uses its data to do the prediction. How can I use the same model to do the prediction for test.csv? Sorry I am very new to Python.

Here is the screen capture for the last few commands and its result for train.csv. When i want to test test.csv i got the following error in last sentence :
https://pasteboard.co/K4p4aZA.jpg

For the test.csv, train.csv and anaconda notebook you can visit: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1U6TcJz8fp7FqbxpUcqRmAU-HSL42VN-S

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_test=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df_train=pd.read_csv("train.csv")

# many lines in between for details please read the notebook in google drive
# below is the last few sentence

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr=LogisticRegression()

lr.fit(X_train,y_train)

#prediction
df_result=pd.DataFrame(y_train)
df_result['predicted']=lr.predict_proba(X_train)[:,1]
```

Comment: Now that your regression model is ready you can read test.csv and test your model. Otherwise if you want to save your model for future usage, you can do that too. Pickle library is a popular tool to save models.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know what needs to type in order to predict for test.csv. Do i need to redefine the X?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your actual code in google drive, but generally you can do something like this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_test=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df_train=pd.read_csv("train.csv")

# I would assume df_test and df_train have exactly the same structure, as it should be.

# You would have some process to clean up your input data
# Abstracted into a function below
def fun(df: pd.DataFrame):
  # Do your cleaning and stuff
  return x, y

x_train, y_train = fun(df_train)


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr=LogisticRegression()

lr.fit(x_train,y_train )

#prediction
df_result=pd.DataFrame(y_train)
df_result['predicted']=lr.predict_proba(x_train)[:,1]

# Now you can do exactly the same thing on your `df_test`
x_test, y_test = fun(df_test)
test_result = lr.predict_proba(x_test)[:,1]
```

I would recommend take a read on `sklearn.Pipeline`, which build one single `Pipeline` to handle both the preprocessing and the actual modeling.

Comment: Sorry i dont really get it, do i need to do one hot encoding for test.csv as well?

Comment: @jonathanchui Essentially everything you did to your `train.csv` should be applied on your `test.csv`

Comment: drive.google.com/file/d/1llyg2rl9TngASxDBMqJE_9jfjKESbBdG/… Sorry can you take a look at the notebook again? I have defined X_test but now it said i havent defined

Answer (score 0):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

from the scikit docs you need to just take your model and predict

```
lr.predict(x_test)
```

where x_test has the same columns.

Scikit learn models have the same fit and predict classes for almost all models.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1llyg2rl9TngASxDBMqJE_9jfjKESbBdG/view?usp=sharing  Sorry can you take a look at the notebook again? I have defined X_test but now it said i havent defined